# What's the difference between LineString and Multipoint in GeoJSON

Tags: gis, geojson

What's the difference between LineString and MultiPoint in GeoJSON?

To me the examples given are identical. http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id3.

I'm planning some things in GeoJSON and if something as basic as this is confusing I'm in trouble.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A LineString is a Polyline or from Wikipedia "a curve specified by the sequence of points". So if you like to do a track or route based on latitude and longitude for a map application - use LineString.

MultiPoint is simply a collection of points without lines between them. Say a group of people. So the use cases are very different.

Answer (score 5):

[Specification of `LineString`](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#linestring) requires at least two positions.

Other than that there is only a difference in intent. `LineString` defines a line through the points in given order. `MultiPoint` defines a finite collection of points.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see that in the definition, but it makes sense from the name.